# no value for parameter - hibernate jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa

i've this query

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT m FROM MenuEntity m WHERE m.idParent = 0 AND m.menuProfiles IN :profile ")
                .setParameter("profile",menuProfileEntitySet);

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "menu")
    public Set<MenuProfileEntity> getMenuProfiles() {
    return this.menuProfiles;
}
```

menuProfileEntitySet is a set of MenuProfileEntity
query failed with error in the question subjecty

Comment: what is the error. Share stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is invalid. You can test if a single menu profile is inside a set, but not if a whole set of menu profiles is in another set. You need a join:

```
select distinct m from MenuEntity m 
join m.menuProfiles profile
where m.idParent = 0 and profile in :profiles
```

That will return all menu entities which have idParent equal to 0 and have at least 1 of their profiles in the given set of profiles.